# How to bind an Arraylist containing items of type object[] to a GridView?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-binding, webforms, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist` in which all the items are of the type `object[2]`.

How can I bind it to a GridView ?

I need to be able to set the `DataField` property on the `BoundField` but I don't know how to do that with an `object[]`.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Linq` to generate list of anonymous objects.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
 {
  List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();
  list.Add(new object[] {11,22 });
  list.Add(new object[] { 21, 32 });

  var result = from ar in list
               select new
                    {
                        Data1=ar[0].ToString(),
                        Data2=ar[1].ToString()
                    };

  GridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

OR

Use `TemplateField` and bind element via `Eval()`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal 
                 ID="lit1" 
                 runat="server"
                 Text='<%#Eval("[0]") %>' />
            <asp:Literal 
                 ID="lit2" 
                 runat="server"
                 Text='<%#Eval("[1]") %>' />                
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind,

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();
     list.Add(new object[] {11,22 });
     list.Add(new object[] { 21, 32 });
     GridView1.DataSource = list;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't use the 2nd method since I'm creating the GridView in code behind and adding a TemplateField would require a lot of code. 1st method works great. Had to convert the ArrayList to a List<object[]> using: var myList = myArrayList.OfType<object[]>().ToList(); Thanks :)